java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked
I got this error when I use JUnit5 for Unit testing:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper
not mocked. at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java) at
androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)

How can I solve this issue?

Step 1 : Add these dependencies in the build.gradle:
implementation("androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.2.0")
implementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0")

Step 2: Add this class to your unit test package:
import androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor
import androidx.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterAllCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext

class InstantTaskExecutorExtension : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {
    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
            override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()
            }

            override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) {
                runnable.run()

            }

            override fun isMainThread(): Boolean {
                return true
            }

        })
    }

    override fun afterAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }

}

Step 3: Use this class as below:
@ExtendWith(InstantTaskExecutorExtension::class)
class CredentialValidationTest {

    @Test
    fun invalidEmail(){
        val viewModel = SignUpViewModel()
        viewModel.createAccount("mail", "password")
        assertEquals(SignUpState.InvalidEmail, viewModel.signUpState.value)
    }
}

